# How to generate logarithms for observations in negative value

Tags: data-transformation, logarithm

I’m doing my VAR regression with panel data on stata 12, but I face a problem with observations that are in negative value when generating logarithms. All the negative variables are missing after transformation in Logs. 
Is it normal or I have to correct this!
Can I have a advice?
Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate.  The OP should read the suggested duplicate linked by T.E.G.